# Rails display techniques by category from associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Categories table looks like this (omitting extraneous info):

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(255) 
  `spanish` varchar(255)
```

Techniques table:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order` int(11) 
  `korean` varchar(255) 
  `spanish` varchar(255)
  `category_id` int(11)
  `belt_id` int(11)
```

Associations have been set up:

```
class Technique < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :belt
    belongs_to :category
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :technique, :order => 'techniques.belt_id, `order`'
end
```

I'd like to show the Techniques in their own page but grouped by categories, not each one individually as I have now. Would also like to be able to edit them and add techniques to a specific category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easy. You do this by passing the value of a category as a hidden option in the create/edit form of a technique, basically you are combining the two forms. On the index of the techniques you can do the same, combine it with the index of categories to list all techniques under a certain category.

in your controller

```
class TechniqueController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

in the view

```
<% @categories .each do |category| %>
  <!-- some category html -->
  <% category.techniques .each do |technique| %>
    <!-- technique html -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is almost what I want, but this produces first a list of categories, then the techniques. I was looking to display the category name and then the list under each one.

Comment: Ok, never mind, I got it, it was bad HTML, this does the trick nicely. Thanks!

Comment: As a followup to this, this bit prints out the proper output: `#{technique.korean}` but sometimes it's empty and when I try to do this: `if technique.korean.empty?` I get an error unknown method empty, but it should work no?

Comment: Also, given this `<% @belts.each do |belt| %>
<h3><%= "#{belt.belt}" %></h3>
<% belt.technique .each do |technique| 
techText = "(#{technique.order}) #{technique.korean} - #{technique.spanish}"  %>
<%= techText %> <br />` which works fine, but I want to again group the techniques by category inside each belt yet I can't quite figure out how to do it because there is no correlation between belts and categories, just belts and techniques.

Comment: you should do a check on `technique.korean.nil?` if it doesnt exist. `.empty?` only works for a few objects, and they have to be NOT null, it checks for arrays if they have entries for example.

Comment: If each technique has a belt and a category you could use, 'has_many/belongs_to' with 'through' http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations to link categories to belts through techniques

Comment: Thanks Ben for both answers here. I shall try .nil? and check the link you sent me to the docs. I really like Ruby, and Rails has some nice magic to it, but it can be daunting when coming from PHP where you simply write everything out yourself.

Comment: However, nil? doesn't work because if the field exists but is empty, korean.nil? comes back as false, so it still tries to display it :( That's why I thought .empty? would be better. Is there perhaps an equivalent to != '' that I could use with that object?

Comment: `blank?` could work, otherwise you will have to make a custom check for this object to see if it does or doesnt have the data you expect